# Did the Standing Rock protestors potentially damage the environment and the local watershed through their own human waste and garbage?

Tags: united-states, environment

[Reuters](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-north-dakota-pipeline-idUSKBN15F05L) has this to say about the mess left behind at Standing Rock and the effort to clean it:

> Dump trucks and heavy machinery rolled into the protest camp near the site of the Dakota Access Pipeline on Monday, and crews began filling large dumpsters with garbage that has accumulated, much of it now buried under snow.
>
> The clean-up marked cooperation among authorities and camp organizers. The decision to clean the site, where a few hundred protesters remain, was made on Sunday by state and local officials and members of the ***Standing Rock Sioux tribe***.
>   Those involved said it was not an effort to destroy the camp, which sits on U.S. Army Corps of Engineers land, but ***a move to prevent waste contaminating water sources***. . .
>
> ***There are dozens of abandoned cars and structures as well as waste at the camp.  “It is paramount for public safety, and to prevent an environmental disaster, that the camps be cleared prior to a potential spring flood***,” said North Dakota Governor Doug Burgum

So is it true that environmental protesters created a situation that would damage the watershed and the environment after the spring thaw at Standing Rock through their garbage and fecal matter?

Comment: If the question is about whether the protesters left dumpsters, then correct it. If the question is about whether that is a potential disaster, it's asking for an opinion. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Sklivvz  So clarified.  Not sure why any of these terms are loaded or opinion based.

Comment: I am still not sure what you are asking: let's take for granted that they abandoned cars, structures and waste. We can also agree on what the consequences of leaving that garbage are. What *is* an opinion, is whether that is a veritable disaster or not. It can be for me, but not for you. On the site we strive to give out fact based answers, but you are asking for a qualitative opinion. Does it help?

Comment: @Sklivvz How about I say damage to the environment and local watershed?  Does that help you?

Comment: I think I give a pretty good objective definition of what a disaster is too that can be evaluated objectively.

Comment: Yes, that would help. It'd be something which is provable or disprovable. I understand that you give a definition of disaster, but the claim originates from Reuters and they don't give a definition.

Comment: @Sklivvz  any chance you worked at the DMV in a past life?

Comment: Unfortunately a lot of claims contain "[weasel words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word)" which makes them effectively unaddressable.

Comment: I'm not even from the US ;-)

Comment: I think we need something more specific than "damage".  By some definitions, every human activity causes some amount of damage to the environment.  "Damage" by definition would mean changes to the environment that are bad, but the question as to whether a particular change is bad or good or neutral is potentially subjective.

Comment: @DavePhD  would the word potential make you feel better?

Comment: @Konstantine Yes, much better

Comment: @DavePhD done per your request

Comment: @Konstantine I retracted my vote to close.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[According to](https://www.gofundme.com/rosebud-sioux-camp-at-standing-rock) Daphne Singingtree of the Standing Rock tribe:

> Everyone shares concerns about the amount of trash, abandoned tents, and other items that are located in the floodplain. Without timely removal, there is a risk of contaminating the very river we are protecting. No one expected thousands, at one point ten thousand people to show up at camp. Then the severe weather came, most people left, leaving behind a lot of stuff and not enough people to process the donations, and then clean up afterwards

Tribal council chairman [David Archambault II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Archambault_II) is quoted making similar statements [here](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2016/dec/1/dakota-access-protesters-accused-of-destroying-env/).

So, yes, because there is waste next to the river, there is potential for environmental damage in the spring when snow and ice melt.